# Won't Iterate Over Array In jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iterator

So I can get all of the images I want into an array and pass them to $image.  However when I try to loop over that array it just keeps alerting the same item 3 times.

The code I'm having trouble with.

```
   getItem : function($image){
    console.log($image)
    console.log(jQuery.type($image))
    var setup ='<img src="' + $($image).attr('href') + '" title="' +    $($image).attr('title') + '"/>';

    $.each($image, function(i){
        alert( setup);
    });

 }
```

The HTML

```
    <a href="images/slideshow/1-GW.PhillipBarnhart.ReverendMemory.jpg" title="Phillip Barnhart as: 
        Reverend Memory - a clergyman who stands for decorum and truth." rel="slideshow"><img src="images/view-slideshow.jpg" width="490" height="352" alt="View Slideshow"></a>
        <a rel="slideshow" href="images/slideshow/2-GW.BethBrooks.POLLYTODD.jpg">fff</a>
        <a rel="slideshow" href="images/slideshow/3-GW.NickHale.NOSTALGIA.jpg">test</a>
```

The whole script or if you like jsFiddle here is a link. http://jsfiddle.net/h3az4/

```
var slideShow = {
config : {
    wrapper : 'body',
    container : 'div',
    anchor : 'a[rel="slideshow"]'
},

init : function(config) {
    $.extend(slideShow.config, config);
    $(slideShow.config.anchor).hide();
    $(slideShow.config.wrapper).find(slideShow.config.anchor)
        .eq(0)
        .show()
        .click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            slideShow.getItem($(slideShow.config.anchor));
        });
},

getItem : function($image){
    console.log($image)
    console.log(jQuery.type($image))
    var setup ='<img src="' + $($image).attr('href') + '" title="' + $($image).attr('title') + '"/>';

    $.each($image, function(i){
        alert( setup);
    });


},

createTumbnail : function($image){

}

};


$(document).ready(function() {
slideShow.init();
 });
```

Comment: I think your `var setup` needs to be declared inside the `$.each` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your using the $.each loop wrong.

Your first problem is that $image.attr("x") will get the attr of the first element in the list if $image is a list. What you want is either $($image[i]) or using `.get`

The second issue is declaring `var setup` outside the loop. Which means its declared and used once rather then 3 times (since you have 3 items).

```
$.each($image, function(i){
    var setup ='<img src="' + $(this).attr('href') + '" title="' +       
        $(this).attr('title') + '"/>';
    alert( setup);
});
```

When your using `$.each` the `this` object in the function will refer to each object in the array in turn. In this case `this` is a DOM object so you want to use `$(this)` to get the jQuery image object.

Look here for a working example http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/h3az4/3/

Answer (score 2):

I assume `$image` is an array since you are looping through it. if that's the case, you want something similar to this...

```
$.each($image, function(i){
    var setup ='<img src="' + i.attr('href') + '" title="' +  i.attr('title') + '"/>';
    alert( setup);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

check my solution at http://jsfiddle.net/h3az4/5/

allows endless loop of your slideshow, imo you've overcomplicated it a bit and made few conceptual errors as @Dutchie432 pointed

hope this will help as well,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you seem to want using [`map()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/map/) .

```
getItem : function($image){
    $image.map( function(i,val){
        return $('<img src="' + this.href + '" title="' +this.title + '"/>')[0];
    }).appendTo(slideShow.config.wrapper);
},
```

This will create a new jQuery object that contains the new `<img>` elements, then will [`appendTo()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) the `slideShow.config.wrapper` selector.

No need for the intermediate `setup` variable.

Or maybe a little nicer like this using the properties object argument:

```
getItem : function($image){
    $image.map( function(i,val){
        return $('<img>', { src:this.href, title:this.title })[0];
    }).appendTo(slideShow.config.wrapper);
},
```