# Iterate over array in jquery and print the text of li elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have already seen [Won't Iterate Over Array In jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798520/wont-iterate-over-array-in-jquery) and [iterate over array in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474206/iterate-over-array-in-jquery) but none of these posts solved my problem.

I just want to iterate over array and print its values in console.

This is my code:

```
var arr= $('#mainmenu3 > ul li').toArray();

                    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                        console.log(arr[i].text());
                    }
```

Here is HTML:

```
<li id="mainmenu3">
 <a class="menu" href="" id="1">MainMenu3<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="">
        <li><a href="" title="">1_SubMenu3</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="">2_SubMenu3</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="">3_SubMenu3</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="">4_SubMenu3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: arr[i].text is not a function
```

Comment: What's wrong with the `each` method?

Comment: @Vohuman There is nothing wrong with  `each`  I want to learn arrays actually ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're trying to use a jQuery method (in this case, `.text()`) on a non-[jQuery object](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/).

Since `arr[i]` doesn't have a `.text()` method, you could change

```
arr[i].text()
```

to:

```
$(arr[i]).text()
```

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/wy0w6uq6/)

In this case, you also don't *have* to use `.toArray()`:

```
var arr = $('#mainmenu3 > ul li');

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log($(arr[i]).text());
}
```

---

You could also just access the text using `.textContent`. In that case, you really don't need jQuery. You might as will just swap your jQuery selector out for `.querySelectorAll` if browser support isn't a concern.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/vg78ebd7/)

```
var arr = document.querySelectorAll('#mainmenu3 > ul li');

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i].textContent);
}
```

---

If you want to use jQuery all the way, just use the `.each()` method:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/pz3u0v2v/)

```
$('#mainmenu3 > ul li').each(function () {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`arr[i]` is plain `HTMLElement` that does not have `text()` method, you need convert `HTMLElement` to `jQuery` Object, like so

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log($(arr[i]).text());
}
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/woqibe/2/edit?js,console)

But in our case better use `.each`, like so

```
$('#mainmenu3 > ul li').each(function () {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/woqibe/3/edit?js,console)